# Django doesn't recognize relation when I define AUTH_USER_MODEL

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt

I'm trying to implement a logout view with JWT. My User inherits used to inherit from django.contrib.auth.models.User, but I changed to AbstractUser thinking that these problems would disappear.

When I define `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'portal.User'` in settings.py and try to run ./manage.py migrate, I get this error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "portal_user" does not exist
```

**settings.py**

```
JWT_AUTH = {
    ...
    'JWT_GET_USER_SECRET_KEY': 'portal.models.jwt_get_secret_key',
}
```

**models.py**

```
def jwt_get_secret_key(user_model):
    return user_model.jwt_secret

class User(AbstractUser):
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    NAME_FIELD = 'name'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'

    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    subscriptions = models.ManyToManyField(Subscription,
                                           related_name='user_subscriptions')
    jwt_secret = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4)
    ...
```

If I remove the `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'portal.User'`, it returns:

```
auth.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.groups'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.groups' or 'User.groups'.
auth.User.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.user_permissions' or 'User.user_permissions'.
portal.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.groups'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.groups' or 'User.groups'.
portal.User.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.user_permissions' or 'User.user_permissions'.
```

I tried to drop the database and create another one, but the problem stills.

Comment: Please show the full traceback that gave the first error. Something seems to be querying your model at startup time, but there isn't enough information here to see what.

Comment: Changing `AUTH_USER_MODEL` after doing any migrations brings all sorts of problems. For more information see this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project

Comment: But what if I delete the database and the migrations and run migrate again? I tried.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the migrations folder. I only had to create it again and put a **init**.py file there.